# Get `.uix` file using Java package

Tags: appium, appium-android

When we take a screen capture of a mobile device using the Appium app, We get a screenshot image file and a `.uix` file. Which can be viewed in the Appium software. I'm running an automation test and am currently taking the screenshot on failure, to know where the test fails. But sometimes the elements seem to be present in the screenshot. So it wud be helpful if I could get the `.uix` file too by using some API. So that I can view them in the Appium software to know what failure has exactly happened.

Answer (score 0):

I found a discussion thread [here](https://discuss.appium.io/t/getting-uix-file-suitable-for-uiautomatorviewer/8422) which does exactly what you need. Check it out and give it a try and let us know here if that approach works.